# Nginx running but not serving on port 80 | Ubuntu 20.04 | EC2 | EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on an EC2 instance in AWS. For some reason when the server is rebooted, Nginx starts but there is no service listing on port 80. When using SSH I can run `sudo service Nginx reload` and everything starts running. Ideas, help and suggestions are appreciated.

See output after a fresh reboot.

```sh
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ ps aux | grep nginx
root         504  0.0  0.1  57184  1460 ?        Ss   10:21   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data     508  0.0  0.5  57944  5368 ?        S    10:21   0:00 nginx: worker process
ubuntu      1039  0.0  0.2   8160  2572 pts/0    S+   10:44   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

```sh
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-02-09 10:21:59 UTC; 8min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 460 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 503 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 504 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1164)
     Memory: 9.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─504 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             └─508 nginx: worker process
Feb 09 10:21:59 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 09 10:21:59 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

```sh
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo netstat -tanpl|grep nginx
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      397/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      628/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      628/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
udp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx           0.0.0.0:*                           397/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:68        0.0.0.0:*                           394/systemd-network 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1/init              
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1/init
```

**Update 1**

It looks like this is an issue with EFS. Nginx configs were saved on an EFS volume and Nginx is loading before the EFS volume has been mounted. I will continue to investigate and read, updates to follow.

Comment: You need to open port 80 for connections. You can do this by editing the ec2 security group. There is no error in the Nginx config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx loads services based on configs set in `/lib/systemd/system/` (Path may change depending on the OS version).

It would seem Nginx is starting before Ubuntu mounts the network drives on startup. Because Nginx was told to load all configs from a directory on the EFS volume, it could not load the configs when launched as they do not exist until the filesystems finish mounting.

This can be solved by telling Nginx to wait for the specific file system to be mounted before starting.

1. Edit the service file by running:
   `Sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`
2. Add the following line under the [Service] section, amending your mount target as needed:
   `After=network.target var-www\x2defs.mount`

If you do not know the mount target you can do the following to find out, replace dir with the dir you mount the drive to.

`systemctl list-units --type=mount | grep /var/www`

Article / Post where I found the information to solve the issue: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246935/set-systemd-service-to-execute-after-fstab-mount